# Google Maps and Siri implementation

Tags: iphone, ipad, maps, siri

Just wondering, can we integrate Google Maps and Siri together. For Example:

> I ask Siri, "show nearest Starbucks" and Siri will open the Map app or Google Maps and show the nearest Starbucks on the map.

Or

> I ask Siri, "show me all Apple Stores". Siri will open the map and show all the locations of Apple Stores on the map.

Is this doable?

I havn't found any good tutorial,documentation to study more about Siri implementation, apart from articles only. There is no technical documentation/API available?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly supported right now, without writing a third party website that Siri can hook into. According to the below linked documentation, from Apple's website, Siri on iOS 6 will support this functionality in at least limited part:

http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/siri/

> **Eyes Free**
>
> Apple is working with car manufacturers to integrate Siri into select voice control systems. Through the voice command button on your steering wheel, you’ll be able to ask Siri questions without taking your eyes off the road. To minimize distractions even more, your iOS device’s screen won’t light up. With the Eyes Free feature, ask Siri to call people, select and play music, hear and compose text messages, use Maps and get directions, read your notifications, find calendar information, add reminders, and more. It’s just another way Siri helps you get things done, even when you’re behind the wheel.

This encourages me to believe that they will also expose the API (because someone will ferret it out if it exists) to normal API consumers during the iOS 6 lifecycle, probably before iOS 6.1, or with that release.

Comment: WOW...this is superb.If apple provides the public API for that, may be lots of gates will be open for implementing lot of things with Siri. Vey informative jColebrand.

Comment: Also, i guess, google created some software with mercedece car. Not sure what exactly, but its in the TV.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible through any kind of API that Apple use. However, there are some third party APIs that you could use such as: https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone You'd have to use that and then pass on the returned data to the Google Maps API.

Although this approach won't be as intuitive as using Siri, since that is not currently possible, this is the best bet you have for the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple has not opened Siri's API to developers yet making this task impossible.  However, Apple will probably open it soon.  If you just want to use it for personal use, check out SiriProxy (https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy).  SiriProxy lets you do exactly what you asked; however, for it to work, you must be on your wifi network so it cannot be in one of your app.  Good Luck!

Comment: thanks Sam for the information. May be in future....we can do lot more with siri.